# React Web// iOS like select dropdown on mobile

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, select

I have a web project built with React. I am trying to open an iOS like select dropdown when user clicks the 'category image button' like the images below.

## What I expect

When I click the 'category image button', iOS like dropdown options should appear.

## My code logic

1. select default style is 'display: none'.
2. when 'category image button' is clicked, it will change 'showWishSelect' state to true & trigger the select click action using select ref.
3. once 'showWishSelect' state is set to true, the style of select will be set to 'display: initial'.
4. then the select options appear. [ image 3 ]

## Issue

When I click the 'category image button', [ image 1 ]

It will display the select input box which I don't want it to be shown in the first place. [ image 2 ]

then I have to click the select input box again to open the dropdown select options. [ image 3 ]

The 'selectRef.click()' doesn't seem to be triggered.

## Code

```
state = {
    showWishSelect: false,
  };

onShowWishSelect = () => {
    this.setState({ ...this.state, showWishSelect: true });
    this.selectRef.click();
  };

return (
  <div className="mobile_filter_icon profile_filter_icon" onClick={this.onShowWishSelect}>
    <select
     size="4"
     style={{ display: this.state.showWishSelect ? 'initial' : 'none' }}
     ref={(select) => { this.selectRef = select; }}
     onChange={(e) => this.onCategory(e.target.value)}
     value={categoryId || 'current-wish'}
    >
     {allWishCategories.length
       ? allWishCategories.map((data, index) => (
         <option key={index} value={data.categoryId}>
           {data.name}
         </option>
       )): null}
     </select>
  </div>
)

/* CSS */
.mobile_filter_icon{ background:url("/.../web/2019/search/btn_filter_right_n.png") no-repeat; width:28px; height:27px; background-size: 28px 27px; }
.mobile_filter_icon.profile_filter_icon { position: absolute; right: 0px; border-radius: 1px; }
```

## What I have tried..

1. delay selectRef.click() event

```
onShowWishSelect = () => {
    this.setState({ ...this.state, showWishSelect: true });
    setTimeout(() => this.selectRef.click(), 1000);
  };
```

2. disable the default select style and add 'category image' to select tag.

```
<select
  size="4"
  className="mobile_filter_icon profile_filter_icon"
  onChange={(e) => this.onCategory(e.target.value)}
  value={categoryId || 'current-wish'}
>
  {allWishCategories.length
    ? allWishCategories.map((data, index) => (
      <option key={index} value={data.categoryId}>
         {data.name}
      </option>
    ))
   : null}
</select>


/* CSS */
.mobile_filter_icon.profile_filter_icon { position: absolute; right: 0px; border-radius: 1px; -webkit-appearance: none; -moz-appearance: none; appearance: none; }
```

### image 1. category button image

[image: category button image]

### image 2. [ bug ] select input box is displayed

[image: bug: select input box is displayed]

### image 3. category dropdown options

[image: category dropdown options]

Thanks for your help in advance !! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<select value={categoryId} className="mobile_filter_icon profile_filter_icon" onChange={e => this.onCategory(e.target.value)}>
    {allWishCategories.map((data, index) => (
       <option key={index} value={data.categoryId}>
          {data.name}
       </option>
    ))}
</select>

/* css */
.mobile_filter_icon{ background:url("//ccimage.hellomarket.com/web/2019/search/btn_filter_right_n.png") no-repeat;width:28px;height:27px; background-size: 28px 27px; }
.mobile_filter_icon.profile_filter_icon { position: absolute; right: 0px; border-radius: 1px; color: transparent;}
.mobile_filter_icon.profile_filter_icon > select { -webkit-appearance: none; -moz-appearance: none; appearance: none; position: absolute; top: -9999px; }
```